# Unable to parse ARGB hex to integer

Tags: java, android, parseint

I'm trying to parse an ARGB hex `String` to an `int` but it's not working.

My code:

```
int color = Integer.parseInt("ff686868", 16);
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'ff686868' as integer
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:438)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:422)
...
```

When I try to parse a normal RGB `String` like `686868` it does work but when I add the alpha it breaks down. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number would be too big for integer.

Use: `Long.parseLong(..)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `java.lang.Long.parseLong()` — `int` is signed so it is only 31 bits + 1 sign bit, and you use all 4 * 8 = 32 bits.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Color.parseColor(String)` to get the int

Answer (score 0):

```
Color.parseColor(String);
```

if itz hexacode do this

```
Color.parseColor("#ffffff");
```